# two-dimensional list error in python

Tags: python

I want to store the guesses of different `iterator` values in two-dimensional list

e.g.,

```
>>>print(characters)
>>>[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

My code:

```
def func1():
    func1.characters = [[]]
    func1.iterator = 0
    func2()


def func2():
    if func1.iterator == 3:
        func1.iterator = 0
    guess = input("Guess A Character: ")

    if not (guess in func1.characters[func1.iterator]):
        func1.characters[func1.iterator].append(guess)

    print("Characters guessed: " + ''.join(func1.characters[func1.iterator]))
    func1.iterator += 1
    func2()
```

I am getting an error saying `IndexError: list index out of range`
I don't know how can I store values in `characters` list

This is what I am trying to do,

User inputs `'a'`, checks if `'a'` is present in `characters[0]` or not, if not, then, value gets stored in `characters[0][0]`, `iterator` increments to 1

User inputs `'b'`, checks if `'b'` is present in `characters[1]` or not, if not, then, value gets stored in `characters[1][0]`, `iterator` increments to 2

User inputs `'c'`, checks if `'c'` is present in `characters[2]` or not, if not, then, value gets stored in `characters[2][0]`, `iterator` increments to 3
, `iterator` changes back to 0

User inputs `'d'`, value gets stored in `characters[0][1]` and so on...

Comment: You are storing values as function attributes, instead of passing them as variables? Also, apart from that, the problem is that your recursive function func2 never stops from calling itself, you have an inifnite loop

Comment: I know, this is the short version of my actual program.

Comment: But when is your "game" supposed to stop?

Comment: I tested my code with passing them as regular variables, it worked. I would like to know what is causing this error? I mean, are function attributes are constants?

Comment: As I said, @OlivierMelançon, this is testing/debugging version of my code

Comment: Umm... reason for down vote?

Comment: Using function arguments like this is just really bad practice and things can go very wrong with that. And, yes I know this is testing, but I need more information about what you are trying to do to be able to help. When is the game supposed to end. What do you want your function to output, etc.

Comment: I am a new learner to Python, just started few days ago, shifting from Java to Python is hard. Some other stackoverflow answers showed my to use function attributes to pass values from one function to another. Please can you tell me whats the difference between using them as function attributes and variables? Also, I have clearly mentioned as to what output I am trying to get, my very first line tells about the desired output

Comment: I suggest you do not use function attribute, I myself almost never see the need to use them. And since you do not want to answer the question of "when should the game stop", I'll let someone you'll be willing to provide more details to help you instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,

Actually, I recently shifted from Java to Python, started learning Python few days ago,

In Java we used to create multi-dimensional arrays like `array[][]`, so in Python, I tried the same thing, `list = [[]]`

But that didn't work, as it is same as `array[][0]`, so to create multi-dimensional array in Python, I did, `lists = [[], []]`, a two-dimensional array.

Comment: Neither of these are arrays, they are *list objects*, which don't have dimensions, but can be arbitrarily nested.